Does an indicator lag in calculations with barstate.isrealtime when the script is laggy?
Assume you have a really big all in one indicator, and you decide to add a feature that uses realtime data with barstate.isrealtime to calculate realtime data with varip variables. Now if the indicator is very laggy, could the indicator skip some isrealtime values?
I have a massive indicator and I tried adding a realtime volume profile to it, and I just want to know if the indicator will skip values because it's huge and it's pretty laggy.

When you execute scripts in real-time, your script will be executed on every new tick update. If your indicator is heavy and the next script comes before the last execution is completed, then you will miss data.
You can use the Profiler to optimize your code.
